# AWS Lex with React and Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am exploring using AWS Lex to add voice recognition to a React / Node web app. Can anyone point me to examples that I can look at?

A major issue seems to be lack of support for MediaRecorder in Safari and IE so I am also looking for plugins that could give my app microphone access.